# derivative of arcsin(x) confusion

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This question has most likely been posted before. However, I had trouble phrasing it in a searchable way. I am having trouble understanding these steps in finding the derivative of $\arcsin(x)$:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3I445.png)

How does $\frac{d}{dx} \sin(x)$ become $\frac{dy}{dx} \cdot \cos(x)$? Doesn't $\frac{d}{dx} \sin(x) = cos(x)$ not $\frac{d}{dx} \sin(x) = \frac{dy}{dx} \cos(x)$? This is most likely a silly question, but I would appreciate it if someone were to clarify. By the way, the screenshot was taken from this website: https://www.wyzant.com/resources/lessons/math/calculus/derivative_proofs/inverse_trig

Comment: They are taking the derivative of $\sin y$, with respect to $x$. $y$ here is a function of $x$; so, the chain rule is used. (${d\over dx} \sin y= \cos y\cdot {d\over dx} y=\cos y\cdot {dy\over dx}$).

Comment: Oh!!!! So they're saying dx/dx = dy/dx * dx/dy?